# Adding JQuery or Javascript on Rails4 loading js.coffee files

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, turbolinks

I'm looking for adding jquery on my Rails 4 project and I'm in trouble with paths.
Below my paths and my application.js config file

```
~/git/myproject$rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0>  y Rails.application.config.assets.paths
---
- /home/flex/git/myproject/app/assets/images
- /home/flex/git/myproject/app/assets/javascripts
- /home/flex/git/myproject/app/assets/stylesheets
- /home/flex/git/myproject/vendor/assets/javascripts
- /home/flex/git/myproject/vendor/assets/stylesheets
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/images
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-7f79dbfcccc2/app/assets/images
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-7f79dbfcccc2/app/assets/javascripts
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-7f79dbfcccc2/app/assets/media
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/jquery-datatables-rails-7f79dbfcccc2/app/assets/stylesheets
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/turbolinks-1.3.1/lib/assets/javascripts
- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

Application

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

it seems fine but I'm  unable to load js.coffee files on /home/flex/git/myproject/app/assets/javascripts
If I try to add `//= require_tree .` I receive the following error when I load a page:

```
Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Mycontrollers#index
```

related to :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I don't understand why the jquery code doesn't works. What's wrong ?

Below the shops.js.coffee file:

```
$(document).on 'page:load' ->
    $('#shops').dataTable()
```

Below the HTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shops</title>
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dataTables/src/demo_table_jui.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/shops.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/userfeedbacks.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="EPJ1cg/DFHrGbKKvpmC5a2n8NzowvCdFCsfRRrSkGPk=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Comment: maybe you missed the dot `.` ? `//= require_tree .`

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I forgot the full stop only in the post.

Comment: can you show your loading.js.coffee?

Comment: may be a error syntax, try this code: `$(document).on 'page:load', -> $('#shops').dataTable()`, note it has a comma `,` after `'page:load'`

Comment: I tried to change that, but nothin changes. I added the head HTML output to underline that shops.js.cofee is not loaded

Comment: so try add `//= require shops` in `application.js` file

Comment: Hi Kien, now it's loaded, the question is how to add  //= require_tree . without receiving errors ?

Comment: where do you place `shops.js.coffee` ? Add this code above your code in `shops.js.coffee`: `$(document).ready -> $('#shops').dataTable()`

Comment: on app/assets/javascripts/shops.js.coffee, it doesn't load except if I put `//= require shops ` explicity on application.js

Comment: of course, you must require it to load.

Comment: you right because I cannot add `//= require_tree .` The question is: how can I add it without receiving error ?